# Is it possible to transfer result set between web services?

Tags: database, web-services

I would like to know if its possible?

Step1: call one web service A which retrieves data from the database and stores in a result set (dynamically)

Step2: web service A calls web service B to process the data stored in the result set.

Is it possible to share result sets which could be of large or small size between web services. If its not possible whats the best options

/SR

Answer (score 0):

Might have more elegant solutions depending on which web services you are specifically referring to, but most of them out there have built-in environment variables, functions, etc.. for parsing the URL string, so you can pass data that way.  Or with cookies. Or with XML or SOAP

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem here. As soon as one web-service can handle data "of large or small size" you can insert another web-service in a middle.

However, there are might be performance penalties in converting data to and from XML/JSON/SOAP  several times.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your execution environment is -- please do, btw -- but in any environment I've heard of or worked in, there are several ways to do what you want to do. Leaving aside standalone programs, interprocess communication is (I claim, without thinking too much) the most common requirement on any OS.

-- b